# Where are the cturtle package sources now?

Tags: ros, cturtle, package, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need to re-compile the *cturtle* sources to provide a *rosnode* for an old machine.

I am using *UBUNTU 10-04*.

For my target hardware I want to use a statically linked binary, so I need to recompile.

The following command fails:

`rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=cturtle&variant=ros_only&overlay=no" ERROR in config: Unable to download URL [http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=cturtle&variant=ros_only&overlay=no]: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`

I learned that `gen_rosinstall` is out of production.

Question:
Is there another way to get the sources for *cturtle*, maybe a mirror of the old installation somewhere?
I looked for it but was unable to find it yet.

Thanks
Uwe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268543/where-are-the-cturtle-package-sources-now?/) by [uwed](https://answers.ros.org/users/31548/uwed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

cturtle is long since EOL'd. Most repositories still have the cturtle tags from that era: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/releases/tag/cturtle  But there's no supported way for collect all the sources. And many of the repositories have moved hosting and to new version control systems since then. You are going to have to do some digging and work to revive a cturtle build.

Though we do still have many of the debian packages available. If you want to revive a specific node I'd recommend starting with the binary packages and then making a small overlay workspace with the minimal source that you need for your rebuild.

Overall I'd strongly suggest that you consider trying to use a more modern version of ROS and Ubuntu. Depending on how much you need to do, moving forward may be less work than trying to revive a system that's ~7 years out of date. I suspect you'll find a lot of resources are now unavailable for that machine.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uwed](https://answers.ros.org/users/31548/uwed/) on 2017-08-14**:
Thanks for your fast response.

Indeed it is difficult to go back to this old software state and I am not sure whether *cturtle* will help in my case. For the proof of concept the binary components and an example I have written using them should be OK.

Regards
Uwe